# not getting url in service worker

Tags: javascript, web-services, push-notification, service-worker

I'm trying to open the url that I should get from the push notification but it's not there in the event.data.json() in the notificationclick eventlistener. However, when I console log data in push eventlistener, the url is there but the url isn't there in the notificationclick event listener. Why so? How can I get the url too in the notificationclick event listener?

```
self.addEventListener('push', (e) => {
  const data = e.data.json();
  console.log('Push', data);
  self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
    body: data.body,
    icon: data.icon,
    image: data.image,
  });
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  const data = event.data.json();
  console.log('Push', data);
  const clickedNotification = event.notification;

  clickedNotification.close();

  const promiseChain = clients.openWindow(data.url);
  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is there in the notificationclick event listener. You just need to access it correctly.

In the notificationclick event listener, the url is stored in the `data.url` property. You can access it like this:

```
const url = event.data.url;
```

Once you have the url, you can use it to open a new window or tab in the user's browser.

For example, you could use the following code:

```
const promiseChain = clients.openWindow(url);
event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
```

This code will open a new window or tab in the user's browser and load the url that is stored in the `data.url` property.